# Убрать редирект на https на кастомном домене ля github pages

Tags: http, https, redirect, github-pages

У меня есть приложение, которое я выложил на Github pages, на нем есть запросы на другой сервер по адресу "http://...", у того сервера нет сертификата, так что работают только запросы на http, на https ответ приходит не приходит. Соответственно чтобы такой запрос браузер не блочил, надо разместить мой сайт также на http. Для этого я подключил к gh pages кастомный домен с godaddy и отключил "enforce https" в настройках репозитория на github. Но мой сайт все также редиректится на https. Как можно отключить этот редирект? И где это делать, на стороне github или же на godaddy? На godaddy не нашел где это можно сделать, на github в настройка вроде уже сделал что необходимо, поможет ли если я добавлю в свой репозиторий .htaccess с настройками редиректа? Будет ли он работать на кастомном домене? Ведь обычно он не работает на пр pages.

Вот ссылка на саму страницу: [github pages](https://showcasepro.online/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в чем дело. Редирект получается отключился через настройки репозитория, но браузер закешировал сертификат безопасности и сам перекидывал меня на https. чтобы решить эту проблему, я зашел в настройки браузера: chrome://net-internals/#hsts и там удалил сохраненный сертификат домена моего сайта.
Теперь при переходе на сайт http://showcasepro.online/ меня не перекидывает и запрос на другой сервер тоже работает. Единственное если зайти опять на https, то сертификат безопасности опять скачается и будет перекидывать меня на https, но как то отключить - я пока не в курсе, по идее нужно удалять ssl сертификат, но в настройках godaddy этого я не нашел.